# How to understand the rarity of a card?

Tags: scrolls

I got some coins and bought a pack. Its description say that I have the possibility to find a rare and two uncommon. I opened the pack but I was not able to understand the rarity of the cards, what I have to look for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Card rarity is indicated by the wear and tear on the scroll image itself, the more worn scrolls being more rare.

I've been looking about midway down the left side of a scroll as that seems to have the most distinct markings.

Here's a common:

[image]

An uncommon:

[image]

And a rare:

[image]

Comment: It is a really strange decision to not have a small symbol printed somewhere, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I agree. wish there was just a symbol for rarity. I'm still struggling to tell a cards rarity without comparing it to others that I know the rarity of. Thanks for the tip though, I think I can do it now with some practice.